# Bootstrapper for SQL Server Express 2005 64 bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Where can I get the 64 bit bootstrapper for `SQL Server Express 2005 64 bit`.  The default bootstrapper is 32 bit only.  This will not install on Vista 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's [SQL Server Express Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/2005/sql/download/) has a link to the 64-bit version, down near the bottom of the page